# How to make logging program with ruby?

Tags: javascript, ruby, logging, error-handling

I know php but my server doesn't support it but support ruby.
But unfortunately, I have few knowledge about ruby.

I just want to save errors of my javascript application and activities of users in the javascript application.

I probably need a ruby program which processes the followings:
- get data which submitted with `jQuery.post()` from the page of the application.
- create a name of a log file which formatted like `YYYY-MM-DD.log`.
- open the log file.
- lock the log file.
- add the data to the end of the file.
- unlock the log file.
- close the log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Logger](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/logger/rdoc/) class in Ruby's standard library should cover your needs. The date can be formatted with [Logger#datetime_format=]. Here's an [example](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_logging.html).

Answer (score 1):

http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_logging.html

may help